# Handle Detail Fragment Rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-rotation

I have a master and a detail fragment in my Activity. In landscape mode both fragments are displayed next to each other. In portrait mode I open a new activity that holds only the detail fragment upon master fragment interaction. 
Like so:

```
if(findViewById(R.id.detail_fragment_placeholder).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    detailFragment.update(content);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(TwoFragmentActivityImplementation.this, FragmentActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

My problem is that if the user rotates the screen back to landscape mode while only the detail fragment is visible, the detail fragment is rotated to landscape and the master fragment does not show up (for obvious reasons as the master fragment is not present in this activity).

My question is how do I handle this scenario, how can I return to the two fragment activity while preserving the state of the fragment from the one fragment activity? I thought opening a new single-fragment activity in portrait is the recommended way to do things. Was I wrong?

Thanks for your input.